# I am getting this error blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in mern

Tags: javascript, cors, spotify

I am currently working on a project where I am implementing Spotify authentication using React for the frontend and Node.js for the backend. Everything is working fine on the backend, but I am facing a CORS issue when trying to handle the Spotify authorization process on the frontend.

Backend (Node.js) code:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.use("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:2002/auth/login");
  next();
});

router.get("/login", function (req, res) {
   // Your existing code to construct the authorizationURL
  const queryString = querystring.stringify({
    response_type: "code",
    client_id: "########",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:7001/auth/callback",
    scope: "user-library-read, user-top-read",
  });

  const authorizationURL =
    "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?" + queryString;

  // Redirect the user to the Spotify authorization URL
  res.redirect(authorizationURL);
});

router.get("/callback", async function (req, res) {
  // ... (Handling Spotify callback)
});

export { router as userRouter };
```

Frontend (React) code:

Frontend code

```
 export const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get('/auth/login')
      .then(response => {
        console.log("success logining in: ", response.data);
        window.location.href = response.data.authorizationURL;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error logging in:', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <button type="submit">Login with Spotify</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The error I am encountering is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id' (redirected from 'http://localhost:2002/auth/login') from origin 'http://localhost:2002' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried adding CORS headers on the backend, but it didn't resolve the issue. I suspect there might be an issue with the way I am making the API request from the frontend.

Could you please help me identify the root cause of this CORS issue and suggest a solution? Any insights or code modifications would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't access https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize with AJAX from the frontend. The problem is somewhere in `// ... (Spotify authorization logic)`.

Comment: @jabaa I added the code inside the /login if you could check it out

Comment: What exactly is unclear? You can't access https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize with AJAX from a browser. A redirect won't help.

Comment: @jabaa I am still new to this, if I can't use redirect what do you suggest I use

Comment: Use your backend as a proxy. Send the request from the backend and send the response to the client

Answer (score -3):

To config CORS on the server side using express you can do something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://example.com',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  credentials: true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Don't forget to install cors using your package manager

Comment: That's not the current question. You can see that the OP already correctly sets the CORS header (you don't need external packages) for the Node.js backend. The OP tries to access the Spotify API from the browser.